# How to recover data from a formatted hard drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery

I am pretty much new to Linux. I had given my hard disk drive (HDD) for someone to install ubuntu. He formatted my entire hard disk drive. I would like to recover some of the images that I lost. Previously my hard disk drive file format was NTFS, now its EXT4. Is there a way to recover it? commands or tools? NB: It had very important photos for me. Like photos of my passed away father.

Comment: were these photos in the old NTFS file system or the EXT4 one?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek those photos where in NTFS. But I was running an ubuntu 11.04. Actually my os was Ubuntu, but files where stored in NTFS(previously I was running a windows, on installing Ubuntu I kept those windows partitions unaltered)

Comment: I was asking cause it is pretty much *impossible* to recover files should the sectors they were on be overwritten. Most of the *good* tools, like photorec work cross filesystem tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, stop using the drive and power off the computer with the drive in question. Continued use can make it harder (impossible) to recover anything that might be there.

Second, consider using a professional service. I'm not promoting anyone or anything here, I'm just saying that recovery can be a tricky business, and if done wrong it can (again) destroy any recoverable data.

If you want to try carving out the files yourself,  connect it to a different machine or boot using a CD, USB or a different HD and run a file recovery or file carver against the drive. Scalpel is one software option. I have another softwarename written down in the office... Will update.

UPDATE:
The name of that other software is Adroit Photo Forensics.